# Error when running odoo from Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, odoo

i'm trying to run odoo from pycharm but when i tried the web app i got "500 internal error" and got the following stack trace:

```
2015-02-23 04:09:13,189 21888 INFO project werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2015 04:09:13] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2015-02-23 04:09:13,196 21888 ERROR project werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/virtenv/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/virtenv/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/odoo-8.0/openerp/service/server.py", line 281, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/odoo-8.0/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 216, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/odoo-8.0/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 202, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/odoo-8.0/openerp/http.py", line 1239, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/odoo-8.0/openerp/http.py", line 1213, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/virtenv/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 588, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/odoo-8.0/openerp/http.py", line 1380, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/odoo-8.0/addons/crm/ir_http.py", line 13, in _dispatch
    response = super(ir_http, self)._dispatch()
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/odoo-8.0/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 49, in _dispatch
    request.website = None
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/virtenv/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 355, in <lambda>
    __setattr__ = lambda x, n, v: setattr(x._get_current_object(), n, v)
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/virtenv/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/fauzan/Projects/virtenv/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 132, in _lookup
    raise RuntimeError('object unbound')
```

For the Run/Debug configuration i use:

- Script: /home/fauzan/Projects/odoo-8.0/openerp-server
- Python Interpreter: Python 2.7.8 virtualenv
- Working Directory: /home/fauzan/Projects/odoo-8.0

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The dependency for my project(xlrd, tools, openpyxl) is the main cause for that error. after I update them to latest version, I can run odoo from pycharm.